# Quiero mover una imagen de una posicion a otra según hago scroll

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Quiero hacer que una imagen se mueva segun hago scroll hasta una posicion concreta. He hecho algo parecido con **switch** en JS detectando los pixels con **window.scrollY** de manera que según el numero de pixeles, el elemento haga un transition:transform. Funciona, pero al reducir la pantalla todo se descoloca y no consigo adaptarlo ni con las @media. Seguro que hay alguna manera para hacer esto bien porque los pixeles al cambiar el tamaño ya no corresponden y no hace lo que busco.
También he probado con if(rango de pixeles) pero nada.

```js
let globo=this.document.getElementById('globovolador');

window.onscroll = function() {
  var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 864px)");
  var y = window.scrollY;
  
  if (!x.matches) {
    
    switch (y) {
      case 0:
        globo.style.transform= "translate(0,0)";
        
        break;
      case 125:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-200px,100px)";
        
        break;
      case 250:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-300px,300px)";
        
        break;
      case 375:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-750px,350px)";
        
        break;
      case 500:
        globo.style.transform= "translate(-800px,500px)";
        break;
      case 625:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-800px,500px)";
        break;
      case 750:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-800px,600px)";
        break;
      case 875||1000:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-800px,800px)";
        break;
        case 1125||1250:
        globo.style.transform="translate(-800px,800px)";
        break;
    }
  }
  
};
```

```css
#separador{
  position: relative;
  height: 1500px;
  width: 100%;
}

#globovolador {
  background-color: #ffde94;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width:40%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0;
  height: 640px;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 2s;
  
}

#mvid {
  text-align: right;
  background-color: #4dbfff;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation: flotacionv 2s linear infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: flotacionv 2s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: flotacionv 2s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes flotacionv{
  0%{transform: translateY(0px); }  
  100%{ transform: translateY(20%);}}
@-webkit-keyframes flotacionv{
  0%{ -webkit-transform: translateY(0px)}   
  100%{ -webkit-transform: translateY(20%);}}
@-moz-keyframes flotacionv{
  0%{ -moz-transform: translateY(0px)}  
  100%{ -moz-transform: translateY(20%);}}

  .todanube{
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
  }

  .nubes{
    background-color: blueviolet;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }


#nube1, #nube2{
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  animation: flotacionv 3s linear infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: flotacionv 3s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: flotacionv 3s linear infinite alternate;
  
}

 
#nube3{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 3;
  animation: flotacionv 2s linear infinite alternate;
  -moz-animation: flotacionv 2s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: flotacionv 2s linear infinite alternate;

}
```

```html
<div id="separador"></div>
  <div class="volador" id="globovolador">
    <div class="mh"> </div>
      <div class="mv" id="mvid">
        <img src="imagenes/Habilidades.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="todanube">
    <div class="nubes scrollear">
      <img id="nube1" src="imagenes/nubesback.png" >
      <img  id ="nube2" src="imagenes/nubesfront.png" >
    </div>
    <img class="scrollear" id="nube3" src="imagenes/nubesback.png" >
  </div>
```

Comment: Pero cual es el error del código actual? que es lo que esperas que suceda?

Comment: No entiendo tu ejemplo, aparecen cosas moviéndose pero sin relación con el scroll

Comment: @pipe  En el ejemplo se ve mal la verdad. Con el servidor de VS code se aprecia mejor. Lo intentaré mejorar. Se trata de una imagen que básicamente estaría arriba y derecha y quiero que se vaya desplazando cuando hago scroll. Si hago scroll hacia abajo, la imagen debe moverse abajo y a la izquierda, y si hago scroll hacia arriba, la imagen debe desplazarse hacia su posición inicial. Pero no todo de punto A a punto B de una, sino que se vaya moviendo por tramos según avanzó con el scroll. Si paro, la imagen debe parar de moverse.